# Android java - Detect Marker inside Radius

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm making an app that requires detection of a marker inside a radius (Circle).

I looked up at the exact same question but every answer was not right.

Code -

```
float[] distance = new float[2];

Location.distanceBetween(marker.getLatitude(), marker.getLongitude(), circle.getCenter().latitude,circle.getCenter().longitude,distance);

if ( distance[0] <= circle.getRadius()){
      System.out.println("inside")
}
else{
   System.out.println("outside")
}
```

This code which I just provided isn't working.

How can I correctly know when the marker inside this circle (radius)?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Apperantly when the marker exactly inside the Circle the input goes as below:

RADIUS: 55.0

DISTANCE: 3275150.9

Comment: Hi, the code should be ok, what you mean for not working? You always get outside? 
Maybe it is a problem when comparing float to double?
Try to print out the two coordinates (marker and circle center) and the radius of the circle, so you can "debug" by hand the values and check

Comment: @NDorigatti Thank you for your reply, yes that's exactly the problem. I already tried what you've suggested, both of them are doubles.

Comment: Not exactly, distance is a float array, while circle.getRadius is not, it's double.
Anyway, can you please put an example of the output of the values when you are expecting inside and instead is showing outside?

Comment: In addition, I would suggest you to check this library: https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils
it has a handy set of methods, like: SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(marker.getPosition(), circle.getCenter());

Comment: @NDorigatti I Edited the thread and gave the "Distance" between the marker and the circle and also gave the "Radius" of the circle.

Comment: ok, looking online and at the method documentation it seems that the method is good for far distances, not close distances.
If you can output the two points you are using for the calculation it would be better to understand completely

Comment: @NDorigatti I was just about to give the two points until I noticed that the marker I used was a different one than the one that I wanted to calculate. After i checked and fixed the two, the calculation was a success and when the marker was inside the circle it was correct. Thank you very much sir for your help.

Comment: Hi! Which jar need to add to my java project to get "Location" class?